# SMSMesssageTracking Data View Field - ResponseToMobileMessageTrackingID

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms, data-views

Is there an example of what populates for 'ResponseToMobileMessageTrackingID' on the SMSMessageTracking Data View? I'm relatively new to MobileConnect in SFMC and read the field description found here(https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) as being a numerical ID associated with a response to an outbound message.

Example:

1. SFMC platform sends a 'welcome' outbound SMS.
2. The recipient replies and their response is assigned a number for the 'ResponseToMobileMessageTrackingID' filed in the data view.

   At this time, I'm unable to query the data view to find out on my own.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great example of how the SFMC documentation is lacking. I queried over 1.5 million records for [_SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) data view and found that the `ResponseToMobileMessageTrackingID` field only returned two results: 'null' or '-1'

I'm assuming this value is system generated but it still doesn't make sense to me what the values of '-1' is supposed to be. It is likely that the data type is supposed to be a boolean value if it is a response to a SMS message, similar to the `Outbound` or `Inbound` fields.